# Is it possible to hide the Digital Crown indicator on watchOS with swiftUI

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

I have been fideling with the Apple Watch and swiftUI for a while now and I'm facing a bit of an issue.

I'm hopping to access the Digital Crown rotation values without having the indicator show up on the watch screen. I have no problem connecting to the crown with swiftUI but I don't seem to be able to hide or remove the indicator it is linked to.

As of today my code is:

```
struct TestView: View {
@State var scrollAmount = 0.0

var body: some View {
            containerView
                .focusable(true)
                .digitalCrownRotation($scrollAmount,
                                      from: 0,
                                      through: 1,
                                      by: 0.05,
                                      sensitivity: .low,
                                      isContinuous: false,
                                      isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
       }
    }
```

Container view is a generic name for a view but not a scrollviews so I can't apply the `(showsIndicators: false)`.
As I said no problem receiving the values on scrollAmount. But everytime the crown is rotated the indicator pops up on the screen.
I try to set `.accentColor(.clear)` but it does nothing and the indicator still appears in green.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? I'm out of idea on how I could tell the system not to show the crown indicator.

Any help or tips is welcome.